# does Azure AD graph API have a isInRole?

Tags: java, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

For the Azure graph API, i am looking for the equivalent of [isMemberOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#isMemberOf) for the isInRole?

The closest functionality i found was [getMemberObjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#getMemberObjects) but it will require processing all the groups and roles on client side.

I was hoping for a simple boolean response to isInRole(roleid).

---update---

i need an fine grain authorisation mechanism for my java webapp.
the normal mechanism that is use is to retrieve the users credentials on login and then retrieve the users roles or permission to grant access to various application specific functionality.

any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you using AAD for a  webapp ?

Comment: hi thomas. yes iam using a java webapp hosted on azure.

Comment: When you get the user claims, application roles are included so you don't need to call the graph api again. Can you check the user claims ?

Comment: @thomas sorry i dont follow what is a "user claims'. there are no such nouns on the graph API.i am more confused because this blog seems to indicated there is a isInRole funciton somewhere. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2014/12/18/azure-active-directory-now-with-group-claims-and-application-roles/

Comment: in this article they explain that you can bind the role or group claim to the IsInRole function (in the .net sdk). Can you edit your question and explain exactly what you are doing ? Is there any Azure AD sdk for java that you can use ?

Comment: There is 3 sample that you can have a look : https://github.com/Azure-Samples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=active-directory-java-

Comment: @thomas. that is the exact code that i am using. there is NO function to retrieve the application role that i see in the example. there is a graph api why the need for a java sdk? editing question with more detail.

Comment: So you are not using SSO ? User authenticate through a custom login page and then you use the credentials to verify authentication and manage authorization ?

Comment: @Thomas i am using the adal4j lib as used in active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect. The SSO is provided by MS. the auth is managed nicely. From what i can see of the code in the other project called active-directory-java-graphapi-web. it is using JSONArray groups = getMembersOf(userObject.optString("objectId"));  This is just getting all the groups and roles and then parsing the list to get roles. if there is something i have missed i would appreciate any help.